# logical replication not copying data from publisher to subscriber

Tags: postgresql

This is postgres 10 on Ubuntu 18.04

I copied over the schema from publisher to subscriber

```
pg_dump -d <db> -s | psql <db> -h subscriber_host -U rep
```

Set wal_level to logical on publisher

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = 'logical';
```

I restarted the database on the publisher

I connected to the database

```
\<db>
```

Created publication

```
CREATE PUBLICATION my_pub FOR ALL TABLES;
```

Then granted privileges to an existing replication user called rep

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <db> TO rep;
```

I am now on the Subscriber

```
CREATE Subscription sub CONNECT 'dbname=<db> host=x.x.0.174 user=rep password=password' PUBLICATION my_pub;
```

Data did not copy over, tables are still empty on the subscriber.

I see the following errors on the log:

```
2020-08-14 01:26:08.055 UTC [21523] LOG:  worker process: logical replication worker for subscription 56144 sync 55996 (PID 435) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-14 01:26:08.057 UTC [437] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "sub", table "wholesaletransfers" has started
2020-08-14 01:26:08.081 UTC [436] ERROR:  could not start initial contents copy for table "public.wholesale": ERROR:  permission denied for relation wholesale
```

Why does it say public.wholesale when wholesale table is in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only granted permissions on the database to user `rep`, but not permissions on the schemas and tables.

The user needs only the `CONNECT` privilege on the database, but it will need `USAGE` on the schemas and `SELECT` on the tables.